Is OSCOLA used only in academic writing or also in court acts and judgments?
Can anyone confirm whether UK judges use the Oxford University Standard for the Citation of Legal Authorities (OSCOLA) when referring to laws and judgments/cases in their judgments (and whether lawyers use it when preparing court acts)?
According to the OSCOLA guide itself, it is used by law schools, legal journals and publishers, but there is no reference to whether OSCOLA is actually used in court/court acts:

"Although originally designed for use within Oxford University, OSCOLA is now
used by law schools throughout the UK and overseas, and by a number of legal
journals and publishers."


united-kingdom

As already mentioned in the answer by Dale M, judgements cannot fully use OSCOLA as there are no footnotes or bibliography. However, I will assume for the purposes of my answer that you are referring to individual citations and elaborate.

The 2001 Practice Direction (Judgments: Neutral Citations) requires the use of neutral citations in judicial judgments and court submissions to standardise case referencing. OSCOLA can be used as a neutral citation for individual cases, but there are other ways to implement neutral citations that do not align with OSCOLA. For example: OSCOLA has specific rules on how to cite secondary sources, international law, and law report series. Neutral citations do not address any of these.
In general, to find information on referencing standards used by judges and lawyers in practice, a good starting point is to refer to the Judicial Practice Directions, the CPR, and CrimPR. If you do this, you will find that none of these mandate or refer to OSCOLA as a required standard.

OSCOLA is not used in judgements
At least, not entirely.
As you can see from this template judgement from the High Court, judgements do not include footnotes or a bibliography and that alone means they don’t use OSCOLA.
However, individual citations, particularly neutral citations of cases are the same as OSCOLA uses.
